# Is there a way to add columns using Text::CSV to create a new column like in R?

Tags: perl, csv

I'm pretty new to Perl programming. I'm trying to parse a file and create a new one using certain columns from the existing file, duh. Using [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV), I have the following code so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

# binary, allow special charachters
# auto diag = 1, report irregularities immediately
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 , sep_char => ',' });

my $file = "Genome_Studio_DNAReport_No_Header.csv";

open(my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $file) or die "Could not open '$file': $!\n";

$csv -> column_names($csv->getline($fh)); # use header to ref cols by name

while (my $row = $csv->getline_hr ($fh)) {    
    print $row->{DNA_ID} ,"\t", $row->{"#No_Calls"}, "\t", $row->{"#Calls"}+$row->{"#No_Calls"}"\n"
}

close $fh or die "'$file': $!";
```

That last part in the `print` statement where I am trying to add `$row->{"#Calls"}` and `$row->{"#No_Calls"}` to create a new column doesn't work obviously, but it's how I would approach it in R. I have looked for a solution to my issue but I'm afraid I'm ridiculously unfamiliar with Perl, and don't understand all of its specific nuances yet.

Can someone help me out and explain to an R user how to make a new variable that combines the two columns I specified above?

Thanks for your suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought there was an issue with your call to `column_names`, as `getline` returns an array reference whereas `column_names` expects a list. But after some experimentation it appears that `column_names` will also accept an array reference. It is just undocumented behaviour. So this is correct

```
$csv->column_names($csv->getline($fh))
```

I would pull out the values to be manipulated and use a simple `join` statement to build the line

The `no warnings` is just to stop it warning me that I may be trying to put comments inside a `qw` list

```
while ( my $row = $csv->getline_hr ($fh) ) {

    no warnings 'qw';

    my ($id, $c, $nc) = @{$row}{qw/ DNA_ID #Calls #No_Calls /};

    print join("\t", $id, $nc, $c + $nc), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Borodin! I would've never thought of that, pulling out the values then using the join statement. I still obv. have a lot to learn about Perl's capabilities. Thanks for the info on the `column_names` statement too. I had that line in my code at another point but I didn't reference `@$headers` properly so I just hashed it out.  Thank you for the info, I added it back in!

Comment: @nchimato: You're welcome. I have just done some testing, and `column_names` actually accepts *either* a list and an array reference, it's just not documented. So your original code should work fine